# Why HttpURLConnection does not send data unless I try to receive something

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I cannot comprehend why doesn't the following code does not put a packet onto wire (confirmed via wireshark). It is a fairly standard method of sending an HTTP `POST` request, as I believe. I don't intend to read anything just `POST`.

```
private void sendRequest() throws IOException {
    String params = "param=value";
    URL url = new URL(otherUrl.toString());
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);    //setting this to `false` does not help
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/plain");
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.connect();
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(params);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    //Logger.getLogger("log").info("URL: "+url+", response: "+con.getResponseCode());
    con.disconnect();
}
```

What happens is... actually nothing, unless I try to read anything. For example by uncommenting the above log line which reads the response code. Trying to read a response via `con.getInputStream();` also works. There is no movement of packets. When I uncomment the `getResponseCode`, I can see that http `POST` is sent, and then `200 OK` is sent back. The order is proper. I.e. I don't get some wild response before sending POST. Everything else looks exactly the same (I can attach wireshark screenshots if needed.). In the debugger the code executes (i.e. does not block anywhere).

I don't understand under what circumstances this can be happening. I belive it should be possible, to send a `POST` request with `con.setDoInput(false);`. Currently it doesn't send anything or fails (when trying to execute `con.getResponseCode()`) with an exception because I obviously promised I won't read anything.

It might be relevant, that before `sendRequest` I do request some data from the same site, but I trust I close everything properly. I.e:

```
public static String getData(String urlAddress) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(false);
    InputStream in = con.getInputStream(); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        data.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    in.close();
    con.getResponseCode();
    con.disconnect();
    return data.toString();
}
```

The server for url in both cases is the same, port also, so I believe it is possible to use the same socket for communication. The above code works and retrieves the data properly.

I am not sure, maybe I don't clean something, and it gets cached, so with out an explicit read the `POST` gets delayed. There is no other traffic on the socket.

Answer (score 9):

Unless you're using fixed-length or chunked transfer mode, `HttpURLConnection` will buffer all your output until you call `getInputStream()` or `getResponseCode()`, so that it can send a correct Content-length header.

If you call `getResponseCode()` you should have a look at its value.

Comment: Is this true even when the user manually specifies a content-length header, as in this case?

Comment: Yes. Setting it manually has no effect. Java always sets it except in the cases I mentioned where it isn't required.

Comment: I don't think looking at it's value makes any difference. There is a `200 OK` message after the file is completed. What is the purpose of `con.setDoInput(false);` then. I obviously cannot use it in this context thanks to buffering. It's quite counter intuitive. I don't think my approach was wrong, yet my code did not work. I do understand that it gets buffered, and of course one should care about the response code. But there is an option, to `setDoInput(false)`. To me it either does not make sense (should be forbidden), or does not work.

Comment: Well I've described how it works. It's up to you to assimilate the information. NB The only way you can know whether there was a 200 response *is* by looking at its value. Your code doesn't do that.